# Cisco IP Phone- How Authenticate with Javascript XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: authentication, xmlhttprequest, cisco

I am trying to write a simple code just to see if I can get my Cisco 7942 IP phone to dial from a web page. So far I have this in my javascript:

```
    var number = "http://172.25.11.59/CGI/Execute";
        var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.open("post", number, "username", "password");
xml.send('<CiscoIPPhoneExecute><URL="Dial:6180" /></CiscoIPPhoneExecute>');
```

The phone...which requires a log in...and I have my own which I am using...does not allow me because I get: "[04:22:15.105] NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied ". I am using Firefox so I do not have to deal with same origin file issue. Any suggestions on how I can get Cisco to allow me to authenticate with XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 0):

This requires:
    xml.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic MTgyMjg6MTgyMjg="); where the password is name:password in base64 encode.  Although, still can't get other parts of this to work with Cisco phone.